# SQL Get total order of managers

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

So in this database the employees make sales and each employee has a manager.

Im trying to figure out how to calculate the sales total by manager.

I found out how to get the sales of each employee but im not sure how to get it by manager.

```
SELECT Employee.Name, SUM(OrderItem.Quantity*OrderItem.Saleprice)
FROM (Employee INNER JOIN [Order] ON Employee.EID = Order.EID) INNER JOIN OrderItem ON      
Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
Group By Employee.Name;
```

Do i just need to order it by manager? or have a where clause to list only the managers?

Comment: in this example provided there is only 1 level deep employee to manager can we assume this will always be the case or could an employee also be a manager to someone else and also report to a manager?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only 1 level of manager to employee exists...
it also assumes managers don't have sales that need to be added in.

```
SELECT E2.Name, SUM(OrderItem.Quantity*OrderItem.Saleprice)
FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN [Order] ON Employee.EID = Order.EID
INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID
INNER JOIN employee e2 on E2.EID = E2.ManagerID
Group By E2.Name;
```

This basically joins to the employee table again to get the managers.

If we need to include manager sales along with employee sales under the same manager
we would need to use an inner join similar to as follows

```
INNER JOIN employee e2 on E2.EID = coalese(E2.ManagerID, E2.EID)
```

coalese grabs the first non-null value in a set of variables.  In this case, since managerID field is null on those records who are managers, we substitute the EID inplace of manager ID allowing their sales to be aggregrated in as well.

However again all this depends on being only 1 level deep w/ managers and having managers whose ManagerID is null.

`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start from your existing query, and `SELECT` and `GROUP BY ManagerID` instead of `Employee.Name`.  I would also alias the tables names, especially `Order` since it's a reserved word.  But you don't need to alias them.

```
SELECT
    e.ManagerID,
    SUM(oi.Quantity*oi.Saleprice) AS sales
FROM
    (Employee AS e
    INNER JOIN [Order] AS o
    ON e.EID = o.EID)
    INNER JOIN OrderItem AS oi
    ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
Group By e.ManagerID;
```

That should give you the total by `ManagerID`.  If you need the managers' names, and those are stored in another table, you can join that table in, too.

Looking again at the screenshot of your table, the first 4 `ManagerID` values are Null.  If the people in those rows are managers, you can join in a second copy of the `Employees` table.

```
SELECT
    e2.Name,
    SUM(oi.Quantity*oi.Saleprice) AS sales
FROM
    ((Employee AS e
    INNER JOIN [Order] AS o
    ON e.EID = o.EID)
    INNER JOIN OrderItem AS oi
    ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID)
    INNER JOIN Employee AS e2
    ON e2.EID = e.ManagerID
Group By e2.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT m.Name ManagerName, SUM(oi.Quantity * oi.Saleprice) Total
  FROM Employee e INNER JOIN 
       [Order] o ON e.EID = o.EID INNER JOIN 
       OrderItem oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID INNER JOIN
       Employee m ON e.ManagerID = e.EID
 GROUP BY e.ManagerID, m.Name;
```